# docker-compose entrypoint with multiple or multiline commands

Tags: docker-compose, docker-entrypoint

How to run docker-compose entrypoint configuration option with multiple or multiline bash commands

commands:

```
yarn install
yarn build
sleep infinity
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how!

**Steps:**

1. In `docker-compose.yml`, say for service: `gvhservice`, add below lines of code

```
  gvhservice:
    entrypoint:
      - "/bin/sh"
      - -ecx
      - |
          yarn install
          yarn build
          sleep infinity
```

2. optionally, add all these commands to a file say - `entrypoint.sh`

Where in `entrypoint.sh`, add below lines of code:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -ex

yarn install
yarn build
sleep infinity
```

where in `docker-compose.yml`, add below lines of code:

```
  gvhservice:
    entrypoint: entrypoint.sh
```

3. By using combination of a docker `ENTRYPOINT` instruction within the container and `command` instruction and operator `|` configuration option in `docker-compose.yml` (suitable for a variable number of commands to be passed during runtime)

build you container with instruction:
`COPY entrypoint.sh .` and

where contents of `entrypoint.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -ex

exec "$@"
```

where in `docker-compose.yml`, add below lines of code

```
  gvhservice:
    entrypoint: entrypoint.sh
    command:
      - "/bin/sh"
      - -ecx
      - |
          yarn install
          yarn build
          sleep infinity
```